# SFMC Cloudpage Execution Context is always load

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, cloudpage

I am making a cloud page to be a subscription centre. When the page is requested with a GET I want the user to submit a form on the page. When the page is requested with a POST, I want to unsubscribe the user.

According to this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/executionContext.htm?search_text=executioncontext) when a cloud page is requested with a get request, `@@ExecCtx == "LOAD"`. When the page is requested with post request, `@@ExecCtx == "POST"`.

However I can't seem to make this happen.

I made a cloud page that posts to itself:

```
%%[
 VAR @key, @test
 SET @key = IsNullDefault(RequestParameter('key'), 'null')
 Set @action = CloudPagesURL(862, 'key', @key)
]%%
<form action="%%=Concat(@action)=%%" name="subscribeForm" method="POST">
    ...
    <br>Context: %%=Concat(@@ExecCtx)=%%
    <br>Request Parameter 'key' : %%=Concat(@key)=%%
    <br>Listname: %%_listname%%
    <br>GET:  %%[[type="Get"]  Output(Now()) ]%%
    <br>POST: %%[[type="Post"] Output(Now()) ]%%
</form>
```

However, even after submitting, and verifying that the request method is POST rather than GET, it seems to display only as a GET request?

[image]

Comment: Please explain clearly what do you want

Comment: Edited to try to clarify my objectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the solution where you set a hidden parameter in your form, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="submitted">
```

Once submitted, you check for the parameter on the same Cloud Page:

```
%%[ IF RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" THEN ]%%
Show content and execute ampscript upon form submission 
%%[ ELSE ]%%
Show form fields
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out!

Answer (score 4):

According to the Ampscript guide:

> In the current release of Marketing Cloud, the @@ExecCtx variable will
>   always return load, irrespective of the context. This is a known issue
>   and should be resolved in a future release.

[Source](https://ampscript.guide/book/execution-context/)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Sadly that does explain a lot. But then how do I get code to run only on a `POST` context? `POST: %%[[type="Post"] Output(Now()) ]%%` didn't work...

Comment: Amazingly over two years later it _still_ doesn't work. Neither does the `ExecutionContextType` attribute for the SSJS script tag.